# How to extract some information from my email?

Tags: external-calls, email

I want to search my email inbox by word "subscriber" and then extract some information from results (precisely from the body of each email). So the following steps should be done:

1. Connecting to the Gmail server
2. Searching my inbox by word "subscriber"
3. Opening all of results (which are about 1000 emails when I did it manually)
4. Extracting the email address in each result  collecting all addresses in a table for example or export them as a excel file.

So I went through these steps:

```
con= MailServerConnect["imap.gmail.com", "user", "pass"];
in = con["INBOX"];
res = MailSearch[in, <|"Body" -> "subscriber"|>];
res // Dimensions
(*{1172, 18}*)
```

the following image shows `res`
[image]

Now I want to extract the body of these results, as you can see there is just "subject" field which can be collected into a table

```
mat = Table[res[[i, 10]], {i, Length[res]}];
```

How can I recall the body of these emails and collect them in a table as above? Also how can I restrict the search to a limited date (for example from 2015 t0 2020)?

Comment: Could you post a small example of "res", the response from the mailserver?

Comment: Mathematica returns `res` as above image. I should use `Normal[res[[1;;5]]]` for example, but it does not give compact form. So please try the steps for your own email to see the result.

Comment: `res[1, "MailItem"]["Body"]`? Can't test it, but reading the documentation helps loads.

Comment: Thanks, yes it works! I wrote `text = Table[res[i, "MailItem"]["Body"], {i, Length[res]}];` and how can I search for a special word in text?